# Help using __call with codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, magic-methods

I have a class in codeigniter which deals solely with ajax. I have created a function within this class which checks if the refferal is an ajax refferal, I want to be able to call this function every time that any function from this class is used.

As such I've implemented the `__call` magic method

```
class Ajax_content extends Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::Controller();


    }

    function __call($method, $arguments){

            $this->ajaxCheck(); //set up to return false and exit.
            call_user_func_array(array($this,"_".$method),$arguments);

        }
```

At present `ajaxCheck()` always returns `false` and `exit()`s. But it's not being called (at present my ajax request still returns data) Is this a valid way of approaching the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to be able to call this
>   function every time that any function
>   from this class is used

[__call](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) is only triggered when invoking inaccessible methods. If you want certain functionality to be executed every time a controller method is called (and by that, I assume you mean a method that's mapped to a web request, not *any* function in the class), **you should put this functionality in the constructor.**

Comment: Thats not what this answer says: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716649/how-to-auto-call-function-in-php-for-every-other-function-call

Answer (score 0):

If you want a method to run before any method instead of use magic php __call in codeigniter controller you can use Remaping method for codeigniter

```
    public function _remap($method)
    {
        // call and start a method before any other method in codeigniter  controller
    }
```

for more info see [this page](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping)