# Calling function at the beginning of every action

Tags: php, function, yii

I'm using Yii, and I have a controller with a few actions.

Besides action, I have a function in the controller which I call at the beginning of every action. Example:

```
<?php

class NameController extends CController
{

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $this->someFunction();

        // ...
    }

    public function actionYolo()
    {
        $this->someFunction();

        // ...
    }

    // More actions ...

    private function someFunction()
    {
        // ...
    }

}
```

So instead of calling the someFunction() at the beginning of each action, is there something else that can do it automatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716649/how-to-auto-call-function-in-php-for-every-other-function-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here.

The first option, override the constructor:

```
    public function __construct()
    {
      parent::__construct(); // Call parent constructor
      $this->someFunction(); // Call your function
    }
```

Don't forget to call the parent constructor (Constructor of the CController class) and after that, call your action.

The second option you have is to override the 'beforeAction' function

```
protected function beforeAction($action)
{
    return true; // True: the action should be executed, false if not.
}
```

Hope it helps you :).

Comment: I used the beforeAction(), thanks. One last question, just so it'll be clear to me - if I want to get a parameter from the url inside beforeAction(), I should use Yii::app()->request->getParam, right?

Comment: Yes that's the function you can use.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `beforeAction`?

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#beforeAction-detail

Comment: Someone is having fun downvoting, but without leaving a comment, which defeats the purpose. @dgross, you gave the the correct answer, but take some time to explain a bit and give an example. The link you provided may not be around in a few months - maybe the reason for the downvote.

Comment: @crafter thank you for your advice! I was wondering about that

Answer (score -1):

A constructor could do this

```
function __construct() {
    //gets called every time you initiate this object
}
```

Comment: Problem is Yii is using this method.

Comment: the constructor is called when making new object and not every time a method of the object is called !