# How to call an function automatically when I call an member functions of class?

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop, zend-framework

In php is there any possible way to call an new function automatically while calling a member function of the class

For Example : I have writing a class with 4 member functions .
And then I have created the object for that class.
Now I am going to call any one of the function as I needed .
When I call an any one of the function of that class . I needed to do some set/Logic , how can I do this

Note: I am not willing to call an new function inside the defined functions and also not need to write a logic for all defined functions . I am looking for any magic methods . Please advice me

```
Class IMAP{
Function IMAP()
{ 
Do something 
}
Function getfolders() {
Do something
}
Function appendmessage()
{
Do something
}
//I need to call the below function     whenever I am going to call any one of the function 
Function checktokenexpired()
{
}
}
```

This class contains lot functions I am not possible to add this function in all functions

Comment: can you show it in code, how you would like  to have it.

Comment: @Mubo I have add the code for ur references . I am in traveling so I can't write much more

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want [a full-blown AOP library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738282/are-there-any-working-aspect-oriented-php-libraries), you can start with a small wrapper like this:

```
class AOP
{
    function __construct($base, $methods) {
        $this->base = $base;
        $this->methods = $methods;
    }

    function __call($name, $args) {
        $this->methods["before_$name"]($args);
        $ret = call_user_func_array([$this->base, $name], $args);
        $this->methods["after_$name"]($ret);
        return $ret;
    }
}
```

Usage like this:

```
class Foo
{
    function bar() {
        echo "bar \n";
    }
}

$foo = new AOP(new Foo, [
    'before_bar' => function() { echo "BEFORE\n"; },
    'after_bar'  => function() { echo "AFTER\n"; },
]);

$foo->bar(); // prints BEFORE...bar...AFTER
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at PHP **magic function** [`__call`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) which allows you to implement method overloading.

Comment: I am not asking about overloading. And I don't understand ur answer can you please explain me it will helps may be

Comment: What you want is not clear, you should edit your question and make it clear for easy understanding. do you need ? like when you call a method which has not yet been defined, a method that is automatically called.

Comment: @zavg hmmm... sadly, `__call() is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an object context. ` his method are accessible

Comment: @Mubo what he asks is pretty clear. he wants a function to execute when calling the methods on an object.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Yes, he should rewrite class (change methods names) and pass calls through `__call` function, as @georg suggests

Answer (score 0):

While what i'm writing here is not an answer per say, You must be exteremely careful when using __CALL as suggested here. The main reason is that you lose all control over visibility of functions, all functions are accessible which may or may not be what you want.

Other than __CALL though, What you want is called a proxy wrapper, Check out the answer by ocramius in this thread :

[How to auto call function in php for every other function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716649/how-to-auto-call-function-in-php-for-every-other-function-call)

Notice that __CALL should always be avoided, if __CALL is the answer, the question is normally wrong.