# Create a before filter method in php

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Just as a learning exercise I'm trying to build my own mini MVC in PHP.

What I want to achieve is a method that can be called before cetain other methods (similar to the before_filter method in ruby on rails)

For example; given the below controller class a user must have permission to do certain activities, so say I wanted to call `checkPermissions()` from `BaseController` before the `create()`, `update()` and `delete()`.

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    beforeFilter(checkPermissions,['create','update','delete']);

    function index(){}

    function create(){}

    function update(){}

    function delete(){}

}
```

Can anyone give me any guidance on how to achieve this? or enlighten me on the PHP way of doing this sort of task. I'm relatively new to PHP so please be gentle.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716649/how-to-auto-call-function-in-php-for-every-other-function-call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make use of the magic method [__call](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods)

That magic method is called every time you call any function within your class.

That way you should be able to do the following:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function __call($method, $arguments)
    {
        if (method_exists($this, $method))
        {
            if (in_array($method, ['create', 'update', 'delete']) && !$this->checkPermissions())
            {
                return null; // Permission is wrong, do something
            }

            return call_user_func_array([$this, $method], $arguments);
        }
    }

    protected function index() {}

    protected function create() {}

    protected function update() {}

    protected function delete() {}

}
```

Please note that this only works for private or protected methods, not public ones.

If you want to use this on public methods, you should apply a decorator pattern like the following example:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function index() {}

    public function create() {}

    public function update() {}

    public function delete() {}

}

class ControllerDecorator {

    private $controller;

    public function __construct($controller)
    {
        $this->controller = $controller;
    }

    public function __call($method, $arguments)
    {
        if (method_exists($this->controller, $method))
        {
            if (in_array($method, ['create', 'update', 'delete']) && !$this->checkPermissions())
            {
                return null; // Permission is wrong, do something
            }

            return call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $method], $arguments);
        }
    }

    private function checkPermissions() {}
}

$homeController = new HomeController();
$decoratedHomeController = new ControllerDecorator($homeController);

$decoratedHomeController->update(); // Will check for permissions
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I am looking for. I will give it a go shortly, thank you so much.

Comment: Note that `__call()` is **not** called if your methods are `public`, but only for `private` and `protected` functions.

Comment: @rickdenhaan `__call()` also works for public methods.
 It works on all inaccessible methods, `__call` is only invoked for members which aren't accessible by the calling code

Comment: @ajimix See https://3v4l.org/sFN5C for an example. You can see that it does not call the `__call` method for the `public function a()`. Public functions are already accessible, so `__call()` is not invoked.

Comment: @ajimix so what u said, those methods are accessible by outside, so your code fails

Comment: @rickdenhaan you are right :) let me edit my answer them to note that

Comment: So this only works if the method is NOT public, which mine are. So this solution is a no go?

Comment: well if you want to use public methods, then the only option would be to use a decorator class which will wrap your other class. I'm going to edit the answer with an example of the decorator pattern

Comment: ok done, I've just added an example with a decorator pattern for public methods

Comment: So if i want to call my index method now, I would call a new 
 controllerDecorator($HomeController)->index

Comment: you can do:
$decoratedHomeController = new ControllerDecorator($homeController);
$decoratedHomeController->index();

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to accomplish this, here's one way to do it:

Create a `beforeFilter` method in your controller:

```
// In HomeController:
public function beforeFilter($action = 'index') {
    if (in_array($action, ['create', 'update', 'delete'])) {
        return checkPermissions(); // where checkPermissions() returns true/false
    }

    return true;
}
```

I assume you have some sort of dispatcher in your framework that knows that for a certain URI, it needs to call the `create` action of your `HomeController`. Before it calls that, you can call `beforeFilter` if it exists:

```
// In your dispatcher class:
public function dispatch($uri) {
    // determine which $controller and $action to call

    $mayProceed = true;
    if (method_exists($controller, 'beforeFilter')) {
        $mayProceed = $controller->beforeFilter($action);
    }

    // note: because we're checking if the method exists, your
    // controller doesn't *need* to have a beforeFilter method.
    // If it doesn't, $mayProceed will simply be true.

    if ($mayProceed) {
        $controller->$action();
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Dispatcher: beforeFilter told me you can't access this page");
    }
}
```