# Laravel php - Do something at the beginning and end of function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to do something at the beginning and end of each function.

instead of doing so

```
public function beforeEveryFunctionCore()
{
   //something
}

public function afterEveryFunctionCore()
{
   //something
}

public function newFunction1(Request $request)
{
    $this->beforeEveryFunctionCore();
    
    //function core
    
    $this->afterEveryFunctionCore();

    return $something;
}

public function newFunction2(Request $request)
{
    $this->beforeEveryFunctionCore();
    
    //function core
    
    $this->afterEveryFunctionCore();

    return $something;
}
```

and so on repeated..(boring)

I would like something like this.

```
public function beforeEveryFunctionCore()
{
   //it does something that is called automatically
}

public function afterEveryFunctionCore()
{
   //it does something that is called automatically
}


public function newFunction1(Request $request)
{    
    //function core

    return $something;
}

public function newFunction2(Request $request)
{    
    //function core

    return $something;
}
```

I know I can do something before every API call with middleware and with construct.
But in this case I talk about any function even those in traits.

How do you think it can be done?

Comment: Please define your use case / goal for this problem, what is it you  want to achieve, Is this for jobs?

Typically there is no such things before  & after event in php class methods.

Comment: Have a read of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54514583/281278). It describes a few different ways to call a function before another but the principle would be the same for after too.

Comment: @PatricNox I didn't define a use case because I have different projects and different situations where I need something like this. One of that is that i need to log information at the beginning and at the end of every function

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single function for all actions, and use a switch to differentiate action function.

```
 public function singleFunction($parameters, $action = 'default')
    {
    // Single function to perform all working
        $this->beforeEveryFunctionCore();
        $this->actionFunctionCore($parameters, $action);
        $this->afterEveryFunctionCore();
    }
    public function actionFunctionCore($parameters, $action)
    {
       switch($action) {
        case 'first':
            $this->firstFunction();
            break;
        case 'second':
            $this->secondFunction();
            break;
        case 'third':
            $this->thirdFunction();
            break;
         default:
            $this->defaultFunction();
            break;
       }
    }
    public function beforeEveryFunctionCore()
{
   //something
}

public function afterEveryFunctionCore()
{
   //something
}

public function firstFunction()
{
   //something
}

public function secondFunction()
{
   //something
}

public function thirdFunction()
{
   //something
}

public function defaultFunction()
{
   //something
}
```

It has benefit like easy to maintain but also
your code will be depend on a single function. You can also make all other function private so they can be use only in a class.