# Auto create logs (inserts data to table) whenever a function was called

Tags: php, laravel-8

I'm new to laravel and to php oop. My **main goal** is to call `createLogs()` everytime a function is called without putting the call method in each function because it's a hassle. I need help please.

I made a controller called `WebLogs` with a function called `createLogs()` that inserts data to a table. I want it to be auto-called whenever another function is called. I tried using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3716750/18159572) and put it in `Controller` class because `WebLogs` extends `Controller` class, and all my other controllers extends `Controller` class, but the solution doesn't seem to work.

So my `Controller` class now looks like this:

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    // Added this function from the solution I mentioned
    public function __call($method, $arguments) {
        echo 'hello world';
        echo '<br><br>';
        echo $method;

        if(method_exists($this, $method)) {
            return call_user_func_array(array($this,$method),$arguments);
        }
     }
 }
```

Example controller:

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        (new WebLogs)->createLogs(); //I don't want to call this for every function
        return view('dashboard');
    }
    public function showSomething()
    {
        (new WebLogs)->createLogs();
        return view('something');
    }
    public function updateSomething()
    {
        (new WebLogs)->createLogs();
        return redirect()->back()->with('message','yeey');
    }
}
```

How the functions from `DashboardController` are being called from `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
Route::get('/something', [DashboardController::class, 'showSomething'])->name('something');
Route::post('/something/update', [DashboardController::class, 'updateSomething'])->name('something.update');
```

Comment: Have you looked into middleware? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware . When coupled correctly you can log each route call with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `app\Classes\WebLogs.php` with content:

```
<?php
namespace App\Classes;

class WebLogs {
    public function __construct() {
      return "WebLogs class with construct function was initialized.";
    }
    public function createLogs($routeName,$routePath) {
      $status = 0;
      logger('WebLogs class is running:');
      logger([$routeName,$routePath]);
      // Save to database here
      // ...
      return $status;
    }
}
```

Then, create an AutoCreateLogs middleware, it will save as `app\Http\Middleware\AutoCreateLogs.php`:

```
$ php artisan make:middleware AutoCreateLogs
```

With content:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Classes\WebLogs;

class AutoCreateLogs
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $route = Route::current();
        $routePath = $route->uri;
        $routeName = $route->action['as'];
        $w = new WebLogs;
        $w->createLogs($routeName,$routePath);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And use this middleware like this:

```
Route::middleware([AutoCreateLogs::class])->group(function () {
  Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
  Route::get('/something', [App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::class, 'showSomething'])->name('something');
  Route::post('/something/update', [App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::class, 'updateSomething'])->name('something.update');
  Route::get('/something/{value}', [App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::class, 'getSomething'])->name('get.something');
});
```

With `app\Http\Controllers\DashboardController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $page = 'index';
        return view('welcome', ['page'=>$page]);
    }

    public function showSomething()
    {
        $page = 'showSomething';
        return view('welcome', ['page'=>$page]);
    }

    public function updateSomething()
    {
        $page = 'updateSomething';
        return response()->json(['page'=>$page]);
    }

    public function getSomething(Request $request)
    {
        $page = 'getSomething';
        return view('welcome', ['page'=>$page]);
    }
}
```

Then, empty `storage\logs\laravel.log`, and run with example route
http://laravel-me.com/something/value99
It will show the successful result:

```
[2022-02-18 22:56:09] local.DEBUG: WebLogs class is running:  
[2022-02-18 22:56:09] local.DEBUG: array (
  0 => 'get.something',
  1 => 'something/{value}',
)
```

Read more about middleware: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware